# google adwords API: how to retrieve all fields(AWQL)

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, ads, awql

ive been looking on Google Adwords API documentation but have no luck, my specific question is:

I need to retrieve all available fields from a report  but there no "SELECT *" statement on AWQL . And selecting every one of them manually is not an option in our implementation due to dynamic report retrieving so , if we cant use "SELECT *" then we need a way to retrieve a list of available fields which will then be used to dynamically create a SELECT AWL statement(in function of the corresponding report). Does anybody knows any way of retrieving a list of available report fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the available fields for each report in the Report Definition Service

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201609/ReportDefinitionService?csw=1#getReportFields

Comment: Any idea, how to get all fields for a given service. For example, all Fields for CustomerService or all fields for CampaignService