# Howto make sure all fields are populated in a Adwords API call (v201609)

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Is there a way to pull/populate all fields while trying to fetch an `AdGroupAd` using Adwords Api?

1. I tried `SELECT *` AWQL call and it failed.
2. Also tried with an empty `fields` with a `Selector` with no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google adwords API: how to retrieve all fields(AWQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352053/google-adwords-api-how-to-retrieve-all-fieldsawql)

Comment: @Casper similar. The answer on the other thread might solve #1 although I need to check how the `ReportDefinitionService` works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the selector definition for AdGroupAd

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/master/modules/ads_lib/src/main/java/com/google/api/ads/adwords/lib/selectorfields/v201609/cm/AdGroupAdField.java

You can make a selector like this.

```
SelectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder().fields(AdGroupAdField.values());
```

Comment: So, that's will set all possible fields?